# Retrieving data from website to iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was recently looking at an example from apple about NSURLConnection and I tried implementing it into my code but I am not sure if am I doing it right.

Basically I want the connection to go to my website where I have it connected to a php script that runs the search within my database and then echo's it to the browser. I want the iphone to take the line that is echoed and hold it into a string variable. This is my code.
Is this correctly done?

Thank you in advance

```
  NSString *stringToBeSent= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
    @"http:/xxxxx/siteSql.php?  data=%@",theData];

      NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
      [NSURL URLWithString:stringToBeSent]
      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
     timeoutInterval:60.0];


   // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
 NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
 initWithRequest:theRequest  delegate:self];


   if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere... in my .h file
    // NSMutableData *receivedData; 

    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

     //convert NSMutableData to a string
    NSString *stringData= [[NSString alloc] 
      initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog (@"result%@", receivedData);

    } else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.


    NSLog(@"failed");

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing a couple things:

1. In the method that you use to trigger retrieving the data make sure you release the old data before initializing:

   ```
   [retrievedData release];
   retrievedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
   ```
2. I assume that space is a typo or something for the URL?
3. You don't need to call `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`   `requestWithURL:` uses the same defaults as you chose.
4. The data will come in blocks.  You've got to handle that over time, outside this method, using the delegate method `connection:didReceiveData:`, like so:

   ```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
   {
        [receivedData appendData:data];
   }
   ```
5. Similarly, if you want something done with the data once it's all received, you do it in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` NOTE THAT THE CONNECTION IS RELEASED so it has to be defined in your header as an instance variable (eg. `NSURLConnection *connection;`

   ```
   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
   {
      NSString *stringData= [[NSString alloc] 
      initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
      NSLog(@"Got data? %@", stringData);
      [connection release];
       connection = nil;
      // Do unbelievably cool stuff here //
   }
   ```
6. Also look into the other delegate methods like `connection:didFailWithError:` You probably want to release the connection and stringData there as well, in case of an error.

I hope that's of some help!  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering what delegate method do I need to declare in my header file? For the methods you noted above aren't been called upon because NSLog does not come up in the console. Will accept!

Comment: You don't declare delegate methods.  Make sure you implement the required methods, even if they're just shells and don't do much of anything. The required methods are  connection:didReceiveResponse:, connection:didReceiveData:, connection:didFailWithError: and connectionDidFinishLoading:.

Comment: Big Nerd Ranch's iOS Programming Guide covers this topic thoroughly. You can download the solutions from their book at http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_nd_edition_  Chapter 26 shows an implementation of this in the ListViewController .h/.m files.  I'd also suggest buying the book - it's a very good read!